# stderr not directed properly

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, io-redirection, stderr

the following command:

```
ls > . 2> error
```

prints:

```
bash: .: Is a directory
```

to the terminal. But since I redirect stderr to 'error' I expect this line to be written into error and not the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirections are done left-to-right, so your stdout redirection fails before your stderr redirection starts. Compare with `ls 2> error > .`

Comment: @Win32: You are redirecting your stdandard output to your working directoy. Aside from the fact that you can not redirect to a directory (as the error message clearly says), what did you want to achieve with the `>.` redirection?

Comment: Nothing in particular, actually. Was just playing around :)